# typekit fonts not properly rendering in IE | CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error

Tags: css, typekit

I am facing this in IE only while in other browsers its working fine.

[image]

I have seen serveral reports on the same on **stack** as well **github**. But I am not able to find anything to work with typekit.

Can you help here how can I fix this issue or I need to report it typekit the issue is at there side?

Please let me know if need to add any extra information here.

Thanks
Aamir Shahzad

Comment: post your `@font-face` code

Comment: @dippas there is no such code as `typekit` take care of all.